# Minimum and maximum summation from array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I want to print the minimum sum and the maximum sum of 4 of 5 elements for my array. When I check my result step by step it seems right, though for main result my answer is false.

```py
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    minimum = 10**9
    maximum = 0
    for i in arr:
        newArray = arr
        newArray.remove(i)
        sumArray = 0

        for e in newArray:
            sumArray += e

    if sumArray < minimum:
        minimum = sumArray
    if sumArray > maximum:
        maximum = sumArray
    
return minimum, maximum

myArr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

> Output: (6, 14)

Has to be (10, 14).

Comment: `newArray` and `arr` are pointing to the same list. You need to make a copy like in the linked question.

Comment: Do you _always_ want the sum of minimum or maximum `k` out of `k+1` elements? If so, you could just do `min_sum = sum(arr) - max(arr)` and analogously for `max_sum`

Comment: yes always k out of k+1 elements and copying the array is fixed my problem

Comment: def f(l):
    l.sort()
    return sum(l[:-1]), sum(l[1:])

Answer (score 0):

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):
    arr = sorted(arr)
    minimum = sum(arr[:-1])
    maximum = sum(arr[1:])

    return minimum, maximum
```

If your goal is to get the min and max sum of all elements except one you can just do this.

Comment: yes but my array can change like arr = [2,5,3,1,4]

Comment: that's why you have to sort

Comment: ok that is useful but i also want to learn what makes my code false.

Comment: If knowledge is what you seek, I suggest this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html